# Is there a Unicode glyph that looks like a "key" icon?

Tags: unicode, icons, key, glyph

Unicode has a million icon-like glyphs, but they're not always easy to search by, since I don't always know what they look like.

Is there a Unicode glyph that looks like a "key"?  Or is there a symbol that's used in database circles to mean "primary key", which *is* in Unicode?

Comment: Gucharmap (Gnome/Linux) and the Character Map (Mac OS X) both have search functions. What do you use?

Comment: I've created a tool for browsing Unicode visually at http://unicodinator.com.  You may be able to find it there...

Comment: In case someone else finds this question while searching for how to render keyboard shortcuts like Ctrl-A, the HTML tag is `<kbd>`.  See [stackexchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5527/keyboard-glyphs) or [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/kbd)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I used a little Python 3 script to look, and the closest I found does not display here for me (does display in Idle on my machine), but it is:

```
9897 ⚩ HORIZONTAL MALE WITH STROKE SIGN
```

(Looks like a male sign pointed right with a perpendicular stroke added between the arrow and circle)

I searched for various matches like "KEY" and "LOCK" in the unicode names using Python's unicodedata module and no luck there.

Editing to add - Ah hah - one that looks even more like a key:

```
9911 ⚷ CHIRON
```

[image]

I give both of the above code points in decimal.  To see them and their hex codes, go to this link:

http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2600.pdf

See 26B7 in particular for the Chiron.

Comment: OK, that's pretty impressive.  I never would have thought to look under astrological signs, or "Chiron".  Unfortunately that's new in Unicode 5.1, which is too new even for me (though that could help explain why I didn't find it).  But it does look just like a key.

Comment: Sorry, but -1 for 3 reasons: **1.** To me, that doesn't look like a key. **2.** Semantically speaking, that is not a key (there are practical implications to this, e.g. screen readers will read it as "Chiron", it may be displayed as a centaur using certain font faces, &c.), and **3.** There is a real key in Unicode: U+1F511 `KEY` 

Comment: For use in XAML &#9911;

Answer (score 113):

U+1F511  [KEY](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f511/index.htm)
(128273 decimal)

Also:

U+1F5DD  (Decimal: &#128477;) [OLD KEY](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f5dd/index.htm)

U+26BF ⚿ [SQUARED KEY](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26bf/index.htm)

U+1F510  [CLOSED LOCK WITH KEY](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f510/index.htm)

U+1F512  [LOCK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f512/index.htm)

U+1F513  [OPEN LOCK](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f513/index.htm)

U+1F50F  [LOCK WITH INK PEN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f50f/index.htm)

[image: key and lock symbols]

Comment: Nice overview, thanks. It's a pity that the OPEN LOCK icon looks almost the same as the LOCK icon. You can barely see that the lock is open.

Comment: @johey Yeah, that's true for Apple and a few other major vendors. Mozilla, Google and Microsoft make the gap wider, and some mobile-centric smart cookies (WhatsApp) make the lock point the other way, so the difference is obvious at any size.

Answer (score 37):

To find useful symbols, I have this resource:

### http://shapecatcher.com

Allows you to draw a shape, which it then searches for similarly shaped unicode symbols.

I often end up using shapecatcher these days just because it's a fun break just to be able to draw the shape that you want and have the site pull it up for you.  At least, sometimes it will pull it up.

### Misc. Symbols Blocks

http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/block/Miscellaneous_Symbols_And_Pictographs is also a great category of unicode symbols, though as with all unicode, you may have to test compatibility.

This is duplicated from my answer here because I think the approach will be useful to others besides just me: [What Unicode character do you use in your website? (instead of image icons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342103/what-unicode-character-do-you-use-in-your-website-instead-of-image-icons/13693154#13693154)

Comment: I'd add an interactive unicode browing tool http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/%2F%5B%5Ebc%5Dlock%7Ckey%2F

Answer (score 11):

Check out #26bf.

```
9919 ⚿ SQUARED KEY (HTML: &#9919;)
```

It's the parental lock, which is a key inside a square.  It's a newer Unicode specification so standard fonts don't support it, but if you can find a font that has it, you're home free.

Comment: That's probably the closest. Also there is a &#x1F511; key symbol.

Comment: FYI this does not render in FF or Chrome + Windows7

Comment: @istepaniuk that would be a font issue, not a browser or OS issue

Answer (score 3):

I've found [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+%22not+equal%22) to be the best way to find Unicode characters.  I didn't find see anything useful for a key symbol, however.

If you want to search visually, use the [PDF charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/), since [HTML-based listings](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html) will only show symbols that occur in the particular set of fonts you have installed.

Lacking any specific symbol, I would just use "I" to indicate an index and "PK" for a primary key.

Answer (score 2):

I browsed through all the symbols (using a PHP script I created a while back) and can't see a key symbol. You could try one of these:

A mathematic-looking P:
ℙ (`#8473`)

Various star shapes:
★ (`#9733`)
☆ (`#9734`)
✶ (`#10038`)

Comment: I think I found those first two star icons at about the same instant you did.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

There doesn't seem to be a unicode character that fits your description, but I'd recommend the [silk icon set](http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/) by famfamfam if you can use icons in your situation--just a suggestion :P

Comment: "Dumb characters delay binding; pretty images induce binding. Moral: Add graphics late in the programming process" -- Alan Perlis's evil graphic designer twin, I think.