# What Unicode characters represent "time"?

Tags: unicode

What Unicode character symbol(s) express duration (such as a clock, hourglass, or other timepiece)?

For example "★3⅔" instead of "3 hours and forty minutes", where ★ is a time symbol.

Comment: What about good old _h_?

Comment: No, he's just being snarky.  Symbols (code points) are Unicode, UTF-8 is only one  of many methods of encoding those symbols.

Comment: If [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon?lq=1) was closed, so should this one.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

The following code points exist related to clocks, watches, and other devices to indicate time:

```
⌚  U+0231A  WATCH
⌛  U+0231B  HOURGLASS
⏰  U+023F0  ALARM CLOCK
⏱  U+023F1  STOPWATCH
⏲  U+023F2  TIMER CLOCK
⏳  U+023F3  HOURGLASS WITH FLOWING SAND
⧖  U+029D6  WHITE HOURGLASS
⧗  U+029D7  BLACK HOURGLASS
  U+1F4C5  CALENDAR
  U+1F4C6  TEAR-OFF CALENDAR
  U+1F550  CLOCK FACE ONE OCLOCK
  U+1F55C  CLOCK FACE ONE-THIRTY
  U+1F551  CLOCK FACE TWO OCLOCK
  U+1F55D  CLOCK FACE TWO-THIRTY
  U+1F552  CLOCK FACE THREE OCLOCK
  U+1F55E  CLOCK FACE THREE-THIRTY
  U+1F553  CLOCK FACE FOUR OCLOCK
  U+1F55F  CLOCK FACE FOUR-THIRTY
  U+1F554  CLOCK FACE FIVE OCLOCK
  U+1F560  CLOCK FACE FIVE-THIRTY
  U+1F555  CLOCK FACE SIX OCLOCK
  U+1F561  CLOCK FACE SIX-THIRTY
  U+1F556  CLOCK FACE SEVEN OCLOCK
  U+1F562  CLOCK FACE SEVEN-THIRTY
  U+1F557  CLOCK FACE EIGHT OCLOCK
  U+1F563  CLOCK FACE EIGHT-THIRTY
  U+1F558  CLOCK FACE NINE OCLOCK
  U+1F564  CLOCK FACE NINE-THIRTY
  U+1F559  CLOCK FACE TEN OCLOCK
  U+1F565  CLOCK FACE TEN-THIRTY
  U+1F55A  CLOCK FACE ELEVEN OCLOCK
  U+1F566  CLOCK FACE ELEVEN-THIRTY
  U+1F55B  CLOCK FACE TWELVE OCLOCK
  U+1F567  CLOCK FACE TWELVE-THIRTY
  U+1F570  MANTELPIECE CLOCK
  U+1F5D3  SPIRAL CALENDAR PAD
```

You can copy and paste the characters from this page into most editors.

At [unicode-table.com](https://symbl.cc/) you might find more useful code points.

Comment: The HTML code for U+0231A is &#8986; in case anybody wanted to look it up, cause I just did.

Comment: or you can do &#x231a; (this means no lookup)

Answer (score 25):

Chars:

```
◴◵◶◷
```

Unicode number:

```
U+25F4 - U+25F7
```

HTML code:

```
&#9716; - &#9719;
```

are working for me

Comment: Interesting, those code points are part of Unicode's [geometric shapes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_Shapes). There's also `WHITE SQUARE WITH UPPER RIGHT QUADRANT` (◳) and friends in the same block. But there's no telling if ◳ denotes 12:15 or 03:00.

Answer (score 5):

A collection of clock faces has been proposed as part of the new Emoji set, in the range from U+1F550 to U+1F55B. Browser/font support is pretty much completely absent, sadly.

Here's one of the clock faces:

[image: Clock face]

Also proposed is an alarm clock symbol at U+23F0:

[image: Alarm clock]

More about the Emoji set [here](http://unicode.org/~scherer/emoji4unicode/snapshot/utc.html).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe **⌛** 
U+231B HOURGLASS

Check that similar question: [What Unicode character do you use in your website? (instead of image icons)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342103/what-unicode-character-do-you-use-in-your-website-instead-of-image-icons)

Comment: Possibly the one before it as well: U+231A ⌚

Comment: For what it's worth, both those characters show up as an empty rectangle on my system. You run this risk if you try to use too-clever Unicode characters, since not all systems display them.

Comment: @Greg what is "the system"? putty+lynx?

Comment: MSIE on Win also doesn't display it either. FF/Safari/Chrome on Win do.

Comment: They display in Mac OS X with Safari for me. They're both contained in the Apple Symbols font.

Comment: These comments nicely illustrate the variance between display of unusual characters on various systems that seem similar but aren't. I might be using a different version of OS X than Adam, but it's hard for your web site to tell.

Comment: It's nothing to do with operating systems or other software. It has everything to do with whether or not one has a font installed that contains a glyph for the codepoint. The days when Unicode parsing and rendering infrastructure support was flaky between browsers and operating systems are long gone.

Comment: right, and some systems come pre-loaded with the right fonts, and others dont.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the [great list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454080/2893496) compiled by [tchrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist) there are some other characters which relate to time and can be used in some situations:

***Weekdays***

```
㊊ U+328A CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH MOON (Monday)
㊋ U+328B CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH FIRE (Tuesday)
㊌ U+328C CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH WATER (Wednesday)
㊍ U+328D CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH WOOD (Thursday)
㊎ U+328E CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH METAL (Friday)
㊏ U+328F CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH EARTH (Saturday)
㊐ U+3290 CIRCLED IDEOGRAPH SUN (Sunday)
```

***Telegraph symbols***

- Months

```
㋀ U+32C0 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR JANUARY
㋁ U+32C1 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR FEBRUARY
㋂ U+32C2 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR MARCH
㋃ U+32C3 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR APRIL
㋄ U+32C4 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR MAY
㋅ U+32C5 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR JUNE
㋆ U+32C6 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR JULY
㋇ U+32C7 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR AUGUST
㋈ U+32C8 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR SEPTEMBER
㋉ U+32C9 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR OCTOBER
㋊ U+32CA IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR NOVEMBER
㋋ U+32CB IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DECEMBER
   All of the above can be composed with a number and
月 U+6708 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-6708 (Definition in English: moon; month; KangXi radical 74)
```

- Days

```
㏠ U+33E0 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY ONE
㏡ U+33E1 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWO
㏢ U+33E2 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY THREE
㏣ U+33E3 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY FOUR
㏤ U+33E4 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY FIVE
㏥ U+33E5 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY SIX
㏦ U+33E6 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY SEVEN
㏧ U+33E7 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY EIGHT
㏨ U+33E8 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY NINE
㏩ U+33E9 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TEN
㏪ U+33EA IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY ELEVEN
㏫ U+33EB IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWELVE
㏬ U+33EC IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY THIRTEEN
㏭ U+33ED IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY FOURTEEN
㏮ U+33EE IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY FIFTEEN
㏯ U+33EF IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY SIXTEEN
㏰ U+33F0 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY SEVENTEEN
㏱ U+33F1 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY EIGHTEEN
㏲ U+33F2 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY NINETEEN
㏳ U+33F3 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY
㏴ U+33F4 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-ONE
㏵ U+33F5 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-TWO
㏶ U+33F6 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-THREE
㏷ U+33F7 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-FOUR
㏸ U+33F8 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-FIVE
㏹ U+33F9 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-SIX
㏺ U+33FB IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-EIGHT
㏼ U+33FC IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY TWENTY-NINE
㏽ U+33FD IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY THIRTY
㏾ U+33FE IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR DAY THIRTY-ONE
  All of the above can be represented by a number with
日 U+65E5 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-65E5 (Definition in English: sun; day; daytime)
```

- Hours

```
㍘ U+3358 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR ZERO
㍙ U+3359 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR ONE
㍚ U+335A IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWO
㍛ U+335B IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR THREE
㍜ U+335C IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR FOUR
㍝ U+335D IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR FIVE
㍞ U+335E IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR SIX
㍟ U+335F IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR SEVEN
㍠ U+3360 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR EIGHT
㍡ U+3361 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR NINE
㍢ U+3362 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TEN
㍣ U+3363 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR ELEVEN
㍤ U+3364 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWELVE
㍥ U+3365 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR THIRTEEN
㍦ U+3366 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR FOURTEEN
㍧ U+3367 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR FIFTEEN
㍨ U+3368 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR SIXTEEN
㍩ U+3369 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR SEVENTEEN
㍪ U+336A IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR EIGHTEEN
㍫ U+336B IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR NINETEEN
㍬ U+336C IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWENTY
㍭ U+336D IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWENTY-ONE
㍮ U+336E IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWENTY-TWO
㍯ U+336F IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWENTY-THREE
㍰ U+3370 IDEOGRAPHIC TELEGRAPH SYMBOL FOR HOUR TWENTY-FOUR
  All of the above can be composed with a number and
点 U+70B9 CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-70B9 (Definition in English: dot, speck, spot; point, degree)
```

***Moon calendar***

```
 U+1F311 NEW MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F312 WAXING CRESCENT MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F313 FIRST QUARTER MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F314 WAXING GIBBOUS MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F315 FULL MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F316 WANING GIBBOUS MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F317 LAST QUARTER MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F318 WANING CRESCENT MOON SYMBOL
 U+1F31A NEW MOON WITH FACE
 U+1F31B FIRST QUARTER MOON WITH FACE
 U+1F31C LAST QUARTER MOON WITH FACE
 U+1F31D FULL MOON WITH FACE
```

***Time of day***

```
 U+1F305 SUNRISE
 U+1F303 NIGHT WITH STARS
 U+1F304 SUNRISE OVER MOUNTAINS
 U+1F306 CITYSCAPE AT DUSK
 U+1F307 SUNSET OVER BUILDINGS
 U+1F309 BRIDGE AT NIGHT
 U+1F0E6 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-6 (Morning)
 U+1F0E7 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-7 (Afternoon)
 U+1F0E8 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-8 (Evening)
 U+1F0E9 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-9 (Night)
```

I cannot fathom why there is pure sunrise, but sunsets only happen in cities.

***Time of year***

Unfortunately there seem to be no pure symbols for times of year, but only with conjunction with other things.

- Games

```
 U+1F026 MAHJONG TILE SPRING
 U+1F027 MAHJONG TILE SUMMER
 U+1F028 MAHJONG TILE AUTUMN
 U+1F029 MAHJONG TILE WINTER
 U+1F0F0 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-16 (spring)
 U+1F0F1 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-17 (summer)
 U+1F0F2 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-18 (autumn)
 U+1F0F3 PLAYING CARD TRUMP-19 (winter)
```

- Unofficially used ([source](https://emojipedia.org/summer))

```
 U+1F331 SEEDLING (Used as spring)
☀️ U+2600 BLACK SUN WITH RAYS (Used as summer)
 U+1F342 FALLEN LEAF (Used as autumn)
❄ U+2744 SNOWFLAKE (Used for winter activities)
```

- Specific celebrations

Many people associate time of year with specific celebrations, but it would be nigh impossible to compile anything that is remotely complete.