# Unicode Character for Funnel to Signify Filtering

Tags: unicode

Is there a unicode character that signifies filtering (for example, a funnel) that is widely available on common computer operating systems?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12036038/is-there-unicode-glyph-symbol-to-represent-search -- I used 

Answer (score 13):

Some of the most similar chars I've found so far:

∀, ∨, ∇, ▼, Y, Ⴤ, V, ᗊ, ⑂,

ツ

Answer (score 11):

You can use search engines that allow you to draw like

- http://shapecatcher.com/
- http://www.mausr.com/
- http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

I'm not able to find anything similar to the funnel but here are some possible results:

- Turned shogi piece: **⛉ ⛊**
- Sector: **⌔**
- Down-pointing triangle with right half black: **⧩**
- Alchemical symbol for water:
- Alchemical symbol for horse dung:
- Canadian syllabics carrier hee: **ᐶ**
- Rightwards arrow through superset **⭄**
- Subset above rightwards arrow **⥹**
- Rightwards arrow through greater-than **⭃** (probably should be rotated when display)
- Greater-than above rightwards arrow **⥸**
- Rightwards arrow with tail **↣**
- Z notation range antirestriction **⩥**

Excel does have a funnel shape when filtering data (see the icon in the `c` column above "7" in the below table) but I'm not sure whether they use an image or character for that since window inspection tools can't work out that symbol

[image: Excel filter]

In some cases the scissors ✀ can be used to signify "cut out unnecessary parts"

Comment: The Excel icons are definitely images, not Unicode characters.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand or maybe it's a custom character in the private use area

Comment: In colour? Although coloured characters seem to be a thing these days, I very much doubt it.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand which color do you see? The character is entirely in black. I'm talking about the funnel in the c column above "7". But the big Filter icon is also in monochrome

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you were talking about the icon in the ribbon. Although the ribbon's funnel icon isn't in colour, the other ribbon icons are, and it would be extremely strange if Microsoft used font glyphs for one ribbon icon and bitmaps for the the rest of them!

Answer (score 6):

This is not really an answer, but possibly useful for anyone finding this page looking for a filter funnel icon. [Here](https://output.jsbin.com/nitejok)'s a hack to make something look like a funnel - stack a triangle and a bar!

```css
.filter-triangle,
.filter-bar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1em;
  text-align: center;
}

.filter-bar {
  top: 0.1em;
}
```

```html
<div class=filter-bar>&#x2758;</div>
<div class=filter-triangle>&#x25BC;</div>
```

Alternatively this is an SVG icon I made:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 80 90" focusable="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="m 0,0 30,45 0,30 10,15 0,-45 30,-45 Z"></path></svg>
```

Both need aria attributes for accessability, amongst other problems! Both snippets are [WTFPL](http://www.wtfpl.net/)-licenced!

Or you can use the MIT licenced [filter icon from Feather](https://feathericons.com/#filter).

Answer (score 4):

I usually use the following:
y filter
Y active filter
¥ cancel or disable filter

Answer (score 3):

Late here, but I like this ⫧
Found it by using shapecatcher.com which someone here suggested.

It works particularly well as a small placeholder in the inputs for my column filters.
[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q34b2.png)

https://unicode-table.com/en/2AE7/

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: He asked for a character, I don’t know what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same, and as far as I can tell there is no FUNNEL, FILTER or REDUCE symbol in Unicode.

However there is this:

`⊆ U+2286 SUBSET OF OR EQUAL TO`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the character "X" with the Webdings Font, and it will give you a **Speaker** icon. Rotate it 90° and it'll be like a **Funnel**.

Answer (score 1):

- Ψ 03A8
- ψ 03C8
- ¥ 00A5
- ⁝ 205D
- ⁞ 205E
- ⥺ 297A (Rotated to point down)
- ⦀ 2980
- ⧨ 29E8
- ⧩ 29E9
- ⧪ 29EA
- ⏚ 23DA
- 128269
- 1F50E

There are a lot pictured here https://www.vertex42.com/ExcelTips/unicode-symbols.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a proposal for a funnel (filter):

https://www.unicode.org/wg2/docs/n5181-repertoire-postAmd1.pdf

**1CE08**

Until it is released, the best character is the one provided by @phuclv (https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728429/5390321)

(1F756)

Answer (score 0):

This is the best character I could find for myself `⊕`

[Unicode Character 'CIRCLED PLUS' (U+2295)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2295/index.htm)

Which is by no means a funnel, but a kind of like a cross-hair insinuating "target more specific results". There are literally thousands of characters though...

In my case, I am going to use IcoMoon to replace the icon for this character, check out the [IcoMoon app here](https://icomoon.io/app/)

If you dont have a character map tool, you can use this quick PHP snippet to print out a range of unicode characters:

```
<?php

for ($i=hexdec("25ff");$i<=hexdec("26ff");$i++) echo sprintf("&#%u; ",$i);
```

Prints

```
◿ ☀ ☁ ☂ ☃ ☄ ★ ☆ ☇ ☈ ☉ ☊ ☋ ☌ ☍ ☎ ☏ ☐ ☑ ☒ ☓ ☔ ☕ ☖ ☗ ☘ ☙ ☚ ☛ ☜
☝ ☞ ☟ ☠ ☡ ☢ ☣ ☤ ☥ ☦ ☧ ☨ ☩ ☪ ☫ ☬ ☭ ☮ ☯ ☰ ☱ ☲ ☳ ☴ ☵ ☶ ☷ ☸ ☹ ☺ ☻
☼ ☽ ☾ ☿ ♀ ♁ ♂ ♃ ♄ ♅ ♆ ♇ ♈ ♉ ♊ ♋ ♌ ♍ ♎ ♏ ♐ ♑ ♒ ♓ ♔ ♕ ♖ ♗ ♘ ♙
♚ ♛ ♜ ♝ ♞ ♟ ♠ ♡ ♢ ♣ ♤ ♥ ♦ ♧ ♨ ♩ ♪ ♫ ♬ ♭ ♮ ♯ ♰ ♱ ♲ ♳ ♴ ♵ ♶ ♷ ♸ ♹
♺ ♻ ♼ ♽ ♾ ♿ ⚀ ⚁ ⚂ ⚃ ⚄ ⚅ ⚆ ⚇ ⚈ ⚉ ⚊ ⚋ ⚌ ⚍ ⚎ ⚏ ⚐ ⚑ ⚒ ⚓ ⚔ ⚕ ⚖ ⚗ ⚘
⚙ ⚚ ⚛ ⚜ ⚝ ⚞ ⚟ ⚠ ⚡ ⚢ ⚣ ⚤ ⚥ ⚦ ⚧ ⚨ ⚩ ⚪ ⚫ ⚬ ⚭ ⚮ ⚯ ⚰ ⚱ ⚲ ⚳ ⚴ ⚵ ⚶ ⚷ ⚸
⚹ ⚺ ⚻ ⚼ ⚽ ⚾ ⚿ ⛀ ⛁ ⛂ ⛃ ⛄ ⛅ ⛆ ⛇ ⛈ ⛉ ⛊ ⛋ ⛌ ⛍ ⛎ ⛏ ⛐ ⛑ ⛒ ⛓ ⛔ ⛕
⛖ ⛗ ⛘ ⛙ ⛚ ⛛ ⛜ ⛝ ⛞ ⛟ ⛠ ⛡ ⛢ ⛣ ⛤ ⛥ ⛦ ⛧ ⛨ ⛩ ⛪ ⛫ ⛬ ⛭ ⛮ ⛯ ⛰ ⛱
⛲ ⛳ ⛴ ⛵ ⛶ ⛷ ⛸ ⛹ ⛺ ⛻ ⛼ ⛽ ⛾ ⛿
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

While it won't be a funnel, I would suggest to use the web symbol:

After all, a web allows to catch the resource after which its user is looking for while letting much of the rest going to some ignored places.

Comment: IMO the cobweb feels more like a catch-all type of capturing. Or filtering that is not instant but actively tracks for matches, for example alerting the user of a new silver items on an auction site.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most fitting and cross system supported Unicode chars / symbols for funnel / filter are Y char and its derived:

Ȳ
Y
Ɏ
Ұ
¥

Answer (score 0):

I keep landing here as a top search result for Unicode filter icon.  This doesn't directly answer the question, but might provide an answer for the next person. It's basically a combination of two Unicode characters, but leverages CSS to overlay one on the other.  There's SURELY a better way to write the transform, but I'm not great at those.

```css
.top_filter_icon {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  transform: translate(-100%, -1px) scaleY(75%);
}
```

```html
<span>▼</span><span class='top_filter_icon'>&#9776;</span>
```

Answer (score -3):

This may help.  While looking for the same thing I found that I could print a funnel using this JavaScript line:

```
String.fromCharCode(57710); // Prints: 
```

But it doesn't work all the time.  Most of the time I end up with a box, like: "".  I'm still trying to figure out why that is.

Comment: That character is from the Unicode "private use area."  Maybe an Apple-specific glyph?

Comment: I'm on a windows 8 PC using Chrome.  I just discovered that same thing does not work in Firefox or IE.  So my answer is likely not very helpful.