# How to add icons in a select using bootstrap 5 and bootstrap icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I would like to add some icons to a bootstrap select like this:

[image: Desired result]

What I've tried:

```
<select class="form-select" aria-label="Filter select">
  <option data-icon="bi bi-funnel-fill" selected>Filter</option>
  <option value="1">All</option>
  <option value="2">Active</option>
  <option value="3">Inactive</option>
</select>
```

I tried using `data-icon` (as I have seen in some stackoverflow answers) but it did not work for me.

I wonder if for bootstrap 5 there is another way to get this result or if I did something wrong.

Any help is welcome.

[LIVE JS FIDDLE DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gerasg/qg1rs2wk/5/)

Comment: Have you tried "<option data-content="<i class='fa fa-address-book-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>Option1"></option>" with bootstrap icons  ?

Comment: Not sure how it works with Bootstrap icons as I always use Font Awesome but.... 
 `<option selected>INSERT-FONT-AWESOME-ICON-HERE Filter</option>` should be somewhere toward what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `<option>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option)'s only permitted content is:

> Text, possibly with escaped characters (like `&eacute;`).

So it's probably just ignored by the browser. When I try `<option selected><i class="bi bi-funnel"></i> Filter</option>` the `<i>` tag doesn't even show up when inspecting the element in Chrome.

You can use an [Input group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/forms/input-group/) or try to find a [suitable UTF character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991395/unicode-character-for-funnel-to-signify-filtering).

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.7.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="input-group">
  <label class="input-group-text" for=""><i class="bi bi-funnel"></i></label>
  <select class="form-select" aria-label="Filter select">
    <option selected><i class="bi bi-funnel"></i> Filter</option>
    <option value="1">All</option>
    <option value="2">Active</option>
    <option value="3">Inactive</option>
  </select>
</div>

<!-- OR -->

<select class="form-select" aria-label="Filter select">
  <option selected>&#x29E9; Filter</option>
  <option value="1">All</option>
  <option value="2">Active</option>
  <option value="3">Inactive</option>
</select>
```