# chrome and opera can't see unicode icons

Tags: browser, unicode

In Chrome and Opera I can't see magnifying glass icon.

What I see instead is - a rectangle.

Firefox - displays the icon.

All the browsers are up to date, on windows 7.

How to solve this.

```html
<input type='search' placeholder='&#x1F50D;'>
```

Comment: For me the magnifying glass is visible in all browsers I've tried (on WIndows 10 though). What happens if you display the `&#x1F50D;` in plain text, using a font that you know contains this glyph?

Comment: @MrLister I tried `Arial` - as plain text - the same result.

Comment: @qadenza Is this still an issue for you? I ran your code snippet in Firefox, Chrome and Opera on Windows 7 and it worked fine using the latest version of each browser, and whatever font gets used by default. Also, though not a duplicate of your question, the answers to [Is there Unicode glyph Symbol to represent “Search”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12036038/2985643) might be helpful.