# How can I display a 'key' in HTML without making an HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I would like to display a 'key' (from a keychain) next to certain key words in an HTML/JavaScript app I'm creating, but I do not want to make any HTTP requests to load an image.  How can I do this reliably across all major browsers?

Is there a UNICODE value that works?  (I couldn't find one)

Is there a Webdings Font that works?  (They don't usually work in Opera and Firefox)

Is there a way to create an image in JS using a base64 image source provided by a String from the JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: This question may help regarding your creating-the-image-with-javascript question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095102/how-do-i-load-binary-image-data-using-javascript-and-xmlhttprequest

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [base64 data in a image's scr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) property:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot">
```

You can then scan through the text with javascript, and add image tags where needed.
(Or wrap the text in a span, and set the image as the span's background.)

---

To actually create a image in the DOM:

```
var img=document.createElement("img");
    img.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38G    IAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==');
    img.setAttribute('alt', 'Red dot');
    img.setAttribute('height', '10px');
    img.setAttribute('width', '10px');
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

---

**Edit:**
[You can use this tool](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64) to encode a image to Base64.

Answer (score 1):

⚿ 0x26BF looks like a good match. I don't know they put the key inside a square, but anyway... Of course the issue is whether the user's font would have the codepoint...

[image]

Comment: The "Webdings" font seems to have a old-fashioned key at 0xD1.