# Is there a downwards double arrow with stroke unicode character?

Tags: unicode, character

I want the character `⇓` with stroke, just like `⇏` but downwards, but I can't find it. Does it exist?

Edit:

If you don't see the arrows (e.g. you use IE),

I want the character `[downwards double arrow]` with stroke, just like `[rightwards double arrow with stroke]` but downwards, but I can't find it. Does it exist?

Comment: If [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon?lq=1) was closed, so should this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such character as a precomposed character (i.e., as a single encoded character, a code point assigned to a character), but you can in principle represent it using an arrow character followed by a combining overlay character.

The character “⇏” [U+21CF](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/21cf/index.htm) RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW WITH STROKE has been defined as having the canonical decomposition RIGHTWARDS DOUBLE ARROW (U+21D2) COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY (U+0338). In principle, a character should be expected to be rendered the same way as its canonical decomposition. In practice, things don’t always go that way.

Along the same lines, a downwards double arrow with stroke could be written as the two-character sequence DOWNWARDS DOUBLE ARROW (U+21D3) COMBINING LONG SOLIDUS OVERLAY (U+0338) or, in HTML, as `&#x21d3;&#x338;`. In practice, few fonts contain these characters, and browsers may fail to implement the combination properly. Moreover, in many fonts, the result is awkward. In Arial Unicode MS and in DejaVu Serif, the result might be acceptable, but only the latter is free (can be legally used as a downloadable font via `@font-face`). Here’s the combination as rendered by your browser with the SO stylesheets in effect: ⇓̸.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to exist, [according to this page](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=DOUBLE%20ARROW%20WITH%20STROKE&preview=entity) (compared to [this](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/search.htm?q=DOUBLE%20ARROW%20&preview=entity)).

Comment: As the answer notes, UNICODE does not have these arrows. What is your use case? Will you be using this in HTML, PDF, or some other document format?

Comment: @DaveNewman I will use it in HTML, so maybe I could use `⇏` and turn it down using css3, but that won't work on old browsers. But how can it be that unicode doesn't have these arrows, if unicode has LOTS of characters?

Comment: @Oriol There are lots of things UNICODE does not have. For HTML, if one of the more commonly used fonts has this glyph in the font, you can use it. I'm don't know HTML well enough to tell you how to construct the reference to the font and the glyph. I did a quick search of Symbol, Windings*, etc. I could not find those arrows there either. CSS is one solution, or creating small images of these symbols and referencing them in the HTML is another.