# Is there a Unicode character for plus over minus? (+/-)

Tags: unicode, character, symbols

Occasionally I've seen the symbol "plus or minus" written in fractional form, like this:

[image: plus or minus]

Is there a Unicode character for this?

**Note:** I already know about the [standard "plus-minus sign" symbol](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm), but it won't work in this context. I'm specifically looking for a version with the fraction bar.

Comment: Yes. ± http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about finding a Unicode character.

Comment: In which forum should I post this, though? There's no Stack Exchange site for typography. :/

Comment: Matt: That's assuming that there is a single character for that and that there are no other means of getting that glyph. That assumption may not be valid and I doubt a search engine might turn up my solution.

Comment: As asked, the question is off-topic here (might be suitable for SuperUser). But the question about *producing* the form may be about programming.

Comment: This seems to me like an alternative glyph for ±, in which case the question would be “is there a font that renders ± with a slash”?

Comment: If [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384380/is-there-a-unicode-glyph-that-looks-like-a-key-icon?lq=1) was closed, so should this one.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is the only one I have seen in unicode (plus over minus):

```
±
```

HTML/XML Character reference:

```
&#177;
```

HTML Named Entity:

```
&plusmn;
```

This symbol is used to indicate the precision of an approximation.

Comment: It's not only used for precision of an approximation. Way back in school we learned a simple formula for the roots of a quadratic function which was x₁₂ = p/2 ± √(p^2/4 - q), where the ± simply indicates two possible choices to make to arrive at two possible results.

Comment: The *correct* use of “±”, by international standards, is to denote two numbers, as in @Joey’s example. Its use to indicate assumed precision or accuracy of an approximation is common but incorrect. It can be used to express tolerances, since tolerances are expressed by two numbers.

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, since the original question is asking for a single Unicode code point. The other answers that show how to approximate the desired symbol are very useful, though!

Answer (score 21):

You can approximate it to some extent with a superscript plus (U+207A), a division slash (U+2215) and a subscript minus (U+208B):

## ⁺∕₋

However, it requires font support to get right. Especially the super- and subscript +/− are not available in most fonts, so it might just render horribly.

For reference, that's how it looks for me (better than five years ago, but still somewhat broken):

[image]

However, using Cambria Math in Word 2010 it looks like this:

[image]

Which probably is exactly how it should look like (follows the same typesetting rules as fractions).

Comment: Looks better for me than for you ;-)

Comment: ⁺∕₋ is definitely the way to go. HTML: `&#8314;&#8725;&#8331;` links: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/207a/index.htm http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2215/index.htm http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/208b/index.htm

Comment: Works great. Swift: `let plusMinus = "\u{207A}\u{2215}\u{208B}"` renders nice with the default font in a`UILabel`.

Answer (score 9):

You mean like  ± (U+00B1 / "\x00b1")?

Edit: speaking specifically to a design which uses a solidus, the best I could find was ⁺⁄₋ which is U+207a (superscript plus sign) U+2044 (fraction slash) U+208b (subscript minus).  The fraction slash has negative kerning in some fonts, which causes the appearance of composition.  See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gqw2D/) for an example of how this works with a larger font size.

```
<div style="font-size:20em;">&#x207a;&#x2044;&#x208b;</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The best combination I had seen

Answer (score 5):

<sup>+</sup>⁄<sub>−</sub>

`<sup>+</sup>&#8260;<sub>&#8722;</sub>`

Answer (score 0):

In UTF-8: 0xC2 0xB1

For other encodings see:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm